# What is the result of this line {} + []?

Tags: javascript

a couple of days ago I had a Javascript exam and the last question was:

When you evaluate the expression `{} + []` what do you get?

1. `Error`
2. `null`
3. `0`
4. `undefined`

I've tested in vscode but I can get an answer :(

Comment: Open the console in your browser and try it

Comment: Press F12 in your browser, go to the Console tab, type it in and hit enter.

Comment: And then, just for kicks, try `[] + {}`

Answer (score 0):

If you simply open your developer tools and type that expression in, you will see the return value as `0`.